# Ionic 3 *ngIf no actualiza la vista

Tags: if, ionic3, vistas

Estoy trabajando con Ionic 3. Cuando cambio el valor de una variable en un componente, no se actualiza la vista en una página donde está integrado.

He mirado muchas respuestas a preguntas parecidas pero no doy con la forma de hacerlo.

Mi código es este:

PÁGINA: home.html

```
<div *ngIf="getLoading()" text-center>
<img src="http://spcdn1.whichairline.com/1c40c0f0542d7227719eccd99bd71fd172d36e0a/images/loaders/loader-search.gif">
<h1><span>Loading...</span></h1></div>
<component-myList></component-myList>
```

home.ts

```
constructor(
public navCtrl: NavController,
public myList: myListComponent) {}

public getLoading() {
  return this.myList.loading;
}
```

COMPONENTE: myList.ts

```
    @Component({
       selector: 'component-myList',
       templateUrl: 'myList.html'
    })



export class myListComponent {

  public loading: boolean = false;

  constructor() {}

  putLoading() {
    this.loading = !this.loading;
    console.log(this.loading);
  }
}
```

myList.html

```
<button color="secondary" (click)="putLoading()" ion-button right>Put Loading</button>
```

Cuando pulso el botón no ocurre nada, es decir, no se muestra el div del home, aunque por consola el valor sí que cambia.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Soy algo nuevo en ionic, pero tengo un problema similar, como fue que se ha creado el objeto "events" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente lo he conseguido con los eventos...

He creado en el constructor de home:

```
 events.subscribe('actualiza', loading => {
     this.loadingLocal=loading;
 });
```

Y en el constructor del componente:

```
events.publish("actualiza", this.loading,1);
```

Cada vez que modifico en el componente el valor de cargando, llamo al evento:

```
events.publish("actualiza", this.loading,1);
```

Y así la página se entera y renderiza de nuevo...